# VBA code in outlook to update a file in teams

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, outlook

I want the user to open their outlook and have a function which will update the TAT(main) file by prompting them to open the source file. The tat file is located in teams/sharepoint.

with my code, it only makes a copy of the main file, which is not what i want.

```
Sub UpdateTATFile()
    Dim tatFile As Workbook
    Dim tatSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceFile As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sourceFilePath As String
    
    ' Open the TAT file from Teams/SharePoint
    Dim sFileName As String
    sFileName = "link.xlxs" ' Update with the actual URL of your TAT file
    
    ' Create a new instance of Excel
    Dim xl As Object
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    ' Open the TAT file
    Dim f As Object
    Set f = xl.Application.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=sFileName, ReadOnly:=False)
    
    ' Set the TAT file as the active workbook
    Set tatFile = xl.Application.ActiveWorkbook
    
    ' Specify the TAT sheet in the TAT file
    Set tatSheet = tatFile.Worksheets("IS PO bookings") ' Update with the appropriate TAT sheet name
    
    ' Prompt the user to select the source file
    Dim fileDialog As Object
    Set fileDialog = xl.Application.fileDialog(3) ' 3 corresponds to the FilePicker dialog type
    
    ' Display the file picker dialog
    If fileDialog.Show = -1 Then ' If the user clicked the "Open" button
        ' Get the selected file path
        sourceFilePath = fileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
        
        ' Check if the user selected a file
        If Len(sourceFilePath) > 0 And Dir(sourceFilePath) <> "" Then
            ' Open the source file
            Set sourceFile = xl.Application.Workbooks.Open(sourceFilePath, UpdateLinks:=False)
            
            ' Find the last row in the TAT sheet
            lastRow = tatSheet.Cells(tatSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            
            ' Retrieve data from the source file and populate in the TAT sheet
            tatSheet.Cells(lastRow, "A").Value = sourceFile.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("F13").Value
            tatSheet.Cells(lastRow, "B").Value = sourceFile.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("D13").Value
            tatSheet.Cells(lastRow, "C").Value = sourceFile.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("D21").Value
            tatSheet.Cells(lastRow, "D").Value = sourceFile.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("D9").Value
            tatSheet.Cells(lastRow, "E").Value = Date
            tatSheet.Cells(lastRow, "F").Value = sourceFile.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("D15").Value
            tatSheet.Cells(lastRow, "G").Value = sourceFile.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("D7").Value
            tatSheet.Cells(lastRow, "H").Value = sourceFile.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("F19").Value
            tatSheet.Cells(lastRow, "I").Value = sourceFile.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("F9").Value
            tatSheet.Cells(lastRow, "M").Value = sourceFile.Worksheets("Order Entry Form").Range("O9").Value
            tatSheet.Cells(lastRow, "N").Value = sourceFile.Worksheets("ENQUIRY - ORDER REVIEW").Range("F27").Value
            tatSheet.Cells(lastRow, "O").Value = "PRV"
            
            ' Close the source file without saving changes
            sourceFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Else
            MsgBox "Source file not found.", vbExclamation
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Save and close the TAT file
    tatFile.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    ' Close Excel
    xl.Quit
    Set xl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Changing `sFileName = "link.xlxs"` to use the URL of the SharePoint file doesn't work?  Did you try that?

Comment: yes, its the  sharepoint link itself.  i  changed it for security reasons here

Comment: You need to make sure the sharepoint link format is correct  - some URL formats are "read only" or "sharing" links which cannot be used to open a file for editing.

Comment: Open your workbook in Excel from SharePoint, then open the VB editor in put `? Activeworkbook.fullname` in the Immediate pane (Ctrl+G) and hit Enter: use the output as the URL in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what is the actual file path is used in the code - whether it is a just file name or fully-fledged URL. Also it makes sense to make sure that manually the same operation can be done without issues.

> with my code, it only makes a copy of the main file, which is not what i want

Mostly Office applications were designed to deal with local files. You need to download the required file locally and only then you can do the required changes using the Outlook or Excel object model.

Comment: You can open an Excel file from a [SharePoint] URL and save changes though?

Comment: May be. For example, Outlook is designed to deal with local files only.

Comment: it is the sharepoint link. there is alot of files to be done manually

Comment: Does it work without problems if you do that manually?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're using the correct URL to open the workbook from SharePoint.  To get the URL, open the workbook from SP for editing in Excel, then open up the Excel VB editor and in the Immediate pane (Ctrl+G) type:

```
? ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

and hit enter.

You'll get something like:

```
https://yourcompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Blah/TestLibrary/_test.xlsx
```

This should work to open the workbook in edit mode when passed to `xl.Application.Workbooks.Open()`

Note: the URL is different from (eg) the URL you get from SP if you use the "Copy link" function in SP:

```
https://yourcompany.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/Blah/Efz3ZR_-JvNEv7n8d9oYq58B7mhqh1GYvCxLdtrxsGu9Bg?e=Ebktf2
```

Comment: I've already tried that unfortunately. it still shows the same thing

Comment: it says the file is open in another application, when its not

Comment: Maybe another user has it open?

Comment: ...or it's open in a hidden instance of excel which is still running on your PC - check Task Manager for any Excel processes